# How to assign two new key values in a JObject from a dictionary?

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, json.net, jsonconvert

Hi I have below method  which I calling in and that generates two string value(Partition Key and Row key). and My json do not have these two keys, so I would like to add these two values in my existing Json.

I need help in modifying my code below to add these two keys and values:

```
internal async Task<(string, string)> GenerateKeys( Dictionary<string, EntityProperty> arg )
{            
    var result = await GenerateValuesFromScript( arg, sbForKeyColumns );
    return (result.First().ToString(), result.Last().ToString());
}

var content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>( lines );
   
await GenerateKeys( jsonDictionary );// above method is called and two values are returned
content.Add( new JProperty( "PartitionKey", "//this is where I have to pass the above 1st values" ) );
content.Add( new JProperty( "RowKey", "//this is where I have to pass the above 2nd values" ) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the result of `GenerateKeys` to a variable.  Since `GenerateKeys` returns a tuple, you can simply reference each of the entries via `Item1`, `Item2`
etc, syntax, adding the properties to your JObject.

```
var lines = "{\"id\": 1}";

var content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(lines);
var keys = await GenerateKeys();// above method is called and two values are returned
content.Add(new JProperty("PartitionKey", keys.Item1));
content.Add(new JProperty("RowKey", keys.Item2));
    

// This is a very simplistic example of your method since I can't reproduce your params
internal async Task<(string, string)> GenerateKeys()
{
    return await Task.FromResult(("PartitionKeyValue", "RowKeyValue"));
}
```

This results in the following JSON:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "PartitionKey": "PartitionKey",
  "RowKey": "RowKey"
}
```

Comment: row key come like this rowkey: [\r\n  0,\r\n  12,\r\n  0\r\n]XTTJF012.any way to fix this while actually the value is [0,12,0]XTTF012

Comment: Are you going to have consistent types in each position? That’s just addition carriage return data that you could trim if you treat every data point as a string.